# Kendo UI: Can't add a node to treeview when using custom schema

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kendo tree initialized with the following datasource:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                url: '/Quota/Home/GetTemplateHierarchy',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { hierarchyID: hierarchyID, quotaSetID: quotaSetID, batchSize: 10 }
            }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: 'id',
                    hasChildren: 'hasChildren',
                    children: 'items',
                    fields: {
                        text: 'text'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Does anyone know how to add and create a new node for this datasource? I've tried the generic treeview.append({ text: "Boo"}) but it doesn't do anything. I've successfully removed nodes, but can't seem to add any. The documentation is not clear as to how to add anything when using custom schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul, I'd like to propose another solution...

```
    <!-- Kendo UI Web styles-->
    <link href="../styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Kendo UI Web scripts-->
    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Local Styles -->
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>

    <!-- Initialize Form Elements -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function loadMore() {
                var uid = $(this).data("uid");
                var node = tree.findByUid(uid);
                tree.insertBefore(content, node);
                tree.remove(node);
                addLoadMore(".k-i-pencil");
            }

            function addLoadMore(clss) {
                $(clss, tree.element).closest(".k-item").on("click", loadMore);
            }

            var content = [
                {
                    text :"node1",
                    items:[
                        { text:"node1.1" },
                        { text:"node1.2" },
                        { text:"node1.3", spriteCssClass:"k-icon k-i-pencil" },
                        { text:"node1.4" }
                    ]
                }
            ];

            var tree = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource:content
            }).data("kendoTreeView");
            addLoadMore(".k-i-pencil");
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tree"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I create a tree with a content loaded from JSON (it should be replaced by your `ajaxAntiForgery`). There is one node in the tree that has an icon (k-i-pencil). Then I call a function `addLoadMore` that intercepts clicks on the node with k-i-pencil and add new content to this node -using `insertBefore` for inserting the new content before the content with `k-i-pencil` and then removes the old node).
I think that this example is pretty similar to what you are doing with your button.
So, take a look into `loadMore` function to see how I detect the `node` corresponding to where I clicked (I extract the `uid` and the find the node with this `uid` by using `tree.findByUid`).
Finally I remove the original node (invoking `tree.remove`) and set again the interceptor for the new nodes with `k-i-pencil`.
Hopefully this is pretty close to what you have.

Comment: I was able to use your above solution for one feature but I now have another feature where I have to be able to add a brand new node and append it to an existing, non-parent node. This means I HAVE to use the append function and for whatever reason, it does not work. I get and error that is reported in the kendo js that says "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'data' of object #<Object> is not a function kendo.web.min.js:25". Any ideas? If i use insertBefore a node, this seems to work, but since that function cannot replicate what I need to do, it's not an option.

Comment: Is it possible for you posting some code in jsfiddle.net showing the error? Another suggestion, if you place a new question here it's likely that just me see it, if it is new -even related- it is recommended asking it as a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you want to be the text of the node that you want to display. So I will guess that you want to display the only element in the schema `nodelevel`

The data in that case should be: { nodelevel : 99 }

Following a complete example where I have an initial node and then I append sub-nodes to the selected node.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Tree View</title>
    <!-- Kendo UI Web styles-->
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Kendo UI Web scripts-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var count = 0;
            var data = [
                { nodelevel: count++ }
            ];

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data  :data,
                schema:{
                    model:{
                        id         :'id',
                        hasChildren:'hasChildren',
                        children   :'items',
                        fields     :{
                            nodelevel:{
                                type    :'number',
                                editable:true,
                                nullable:false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            var tree = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource   :dataSource,
                dataTextField:"nodelevel"
            }).data("kendoTreeView");

            $("#add").click(function () {
                var selected = tree.select();
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    tree.append({ nodelevel: count++ }, selected);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="add">Add to selected</a>

<div id="tree"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've changed the my sample to better reflect what I want to show. I have a basic text label and I still cannot use the append method. I am trying to use tree.append({ text: "boo"}) without the final argument (as it is optional.) Is that not valid?

Comment: I should add that I am using Kendo v2012.2.924

Comment: Playing around with it some more, I've noticed a weird pattern. I am now able to use append, but only if I do not call detach() on the previous node. If i call detach (on the node previous to the one being added) and then append, the append fails. If I call my detach before it fails... I wonder if how I'm selecting the previous node, it was somehow selecting the one I just created. Anyways, it works now.

Comment: On a sort of related note, I would like to be able to append the node to a specific node in the tree. I know there is an option to provide the parent node, but it doesn't seem to work when using jquery to select the node. What format is that node supposed to be in? Again, documentation not clear.

Comment: @PaulSachs, do you know jsfiddle.com or jsbin.com? Would be possible to put your code there and I would take a look into it? I'm somehow confused about what you mean bu previous / parent / detach / ... Also important to note that with last week release, they have fixed a lot of bugs but I think what you are trying should also work with 2012.2.924.

Comment: It is a little tough to write something out in jsfiddle because there are many other pieces around it. Essentially what I am trying to do is have a button as the last child of each node. This button, when pressed will disappear (detach) and will fetch more data. Everything is working except for if the button I press is a child element and I try to append the new nodes to it's parent. I try to use jquery to select the parent but it doesn't seem to work, the error saying HTMLLIElement doesn't contain property "children". You can find the "click" function here: http://jsfiddle.net/m43Py/

Comment: Now, I start understanding why the detach and why the question of the parent... Would be possible for you move to 2012 Q3 release? As mentioned before, they fixed a lot of bugs there and might worthwhile trying it. Nevertheless, I'm experiencing problem (even in 2012Q3 release) and other users too. I'll take a look into your code and I let you know.

Comment: I'll look into if the upgrade is possible. I'm not the only one this will affect so please see if there is a workaround.

Comment: I have discovered a work around that is kludgy but does work. I call treeView.select(parent_nodes[0]);var selected = treeView.select();
treeView.append(response, selected);
It works but it forces the select of the parent, which is not ideal.

Comment: Using what I propose as another solution, I've modified the fiddle and you can find it [http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/m43Py/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/m43Py/1/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19963/discussion-between-emiliano-bartolome-and-paul-sachs)

Answer (score 0):

The **treeview.append** should work and append new node to the root level if you do not specify a note to append it to.

You could also use the dataSource.[insert](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#insert)({text:"foo"}) or **dataSource.add**.